# Remove entire xml node

Tags: java, xml, sax, jdom, jdom-2

I try to remove a node from my xml with jdom2 but i don't find the answer

my xml is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<banque>
  <compte idCompte="5646">
    <numCompte>5646</numCompte>
    <nom>Ludo</nom>
    <solde>850</solde>
  </compte>
  <compte idCompte="4546">
    <numCompte>4546</numCompte>
    <nom>Antoine</nom>
    <solde>9999.4</solde>
  </compte>
```

i think i need to target the attribute idCompte and remove it but i don't know how to do this.

if you have a (simple) solution i'm very pleased to see :)

Comment: You want jdom2 code to remove the idComplete attribute of node compte ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
What you are trying to achieve is complex(multi-step process) in nature,
I can share with you the steps(algorithm) that you need to follow:

Step:1
You need to genearte the schema first:
Generate the schema from this online tool: 
http://www.xmlforasp.net/CodeBank/System_Xml_Schema/BuildSchema/BuildXMLSchema.aspx

Step:2
Using these schema generate the Java classes:
using api tools like XMLBeans or JAXB
a) scomp -out employeeschema.jar employeeschema.xsd (Ref: http://xmlbeans.apache.org/)
b) xjc -d out customer.xsd (Ref: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/10/jaxb-xjc-imported-schemas-and-xml.html)

Step:3 
Then follow below tutorial for your reference for in-depth CRUD operation that you want to perform on your XML:
Jaxb: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/
Xstream: http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html
XMLBeans: http://xmlbeans.apache.org/documentation/tutorial_getstarted.html
```

Comment: Thanks for the step :) nevertheless i've find the solution in stackoverflow using Xpath i liked the post or my java if i don't refind it.